# MATLAB Repeat String n times with using textscan() using end of line wrap

Tags: matlab

(Edited) We have a string and want it to be repeated, say 5 times, namely from

```
  str = '%s ';
```

to

```
'%s %s %s %s %s '
```

Question 1: How to specify in the the format argument in `textscan()` function, to create a new line every 5 strings? I'm looking for something like `[repmat('%s', 1, 5) '%*[^\n]']` (this doesn't work).

Question 2: the `[data] = textscan(fid, [repmat('%s', 1, 5) '%*[^\n]'], 'Delimiter',{','},'headerLines', 1)` currently gives me a `1`x`n` cell - how to convert this into a `m`x`n` matrix?;

Comment: Try repmat(str, 1, n)

Answer (score 1):

Use [repmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat copies of an array. Pass 1 row and n columns to represent it as an array.

```
>>  str = '%s ';
>> repmat(str, 1, 5)

ans =

%s %s %s %s %s
```

Comment: I tried `repmat(str, 1, 5)` - however it doesn't wrap every 5 strings, please see my edited question. Thank you